# command cmd on vb.net

Tags: wpf, vb.net

i hope you will help me to found a solution for my problem,so I want to zipp a file with a command cmd on WPF vb.net so i create a boutton which get the path of the folder i want to zipper .But the command doesn't work 
this is the code :

```
    Private Sub click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles button.Click
        Dim folder As New FolderBrowserDialog
        folder.ShowDialog()
        Dim A As String

        A = folder.SelectedPath
        textBox.Text = A

    End Sub

    Private Sub executer(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles button1.Click
        Dim myProcess As New Process()
        myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe"  
        myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "7z a -v10m NF.7z A"  
        'myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
        'myProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
        myProcess.Start()  
        myProcess.WaitForExit()  
        myProcess.Close()  
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You should 7z say, what your achive file is and what you want to pack.

Comment: the command is:   7z a -v10m nf.7z(nom du nv fragments)  A (folder path)

Comment: Why do you want to start `cmd.exe` instead of starting `7z`?

Comment: Adding to my last comment, why do you want to use 7z instead of just using the .Net internal zipping functionality and avoiding external program calls completely?

Comment: Because i need it in my project ....also i need to fragment the folder in splites

Comment: If your command is working with opened cmd, then how about starting the arguments with `/C` ([Options: /C     Run Command and then terminate](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html))?

Comment: thank you ...i just add in my code and i don't  know the problem nothing happen  even i try it  the command and it works in the cmd.

Comment: What if you use /K instead of /C so you can inspect the CMD before its closing? Also, please use @grek40 if you want to answer me, else I don't get notified.

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't work :(